# Angular 2 join nested observables

Tags: angular, observable

I am looking for a solution for nested observables in angular 2.

Most of the examples I see involve making an extra http request for each object returned by an initial request. In my case, I want to make the first request for the objects, then a second request which gets the state of all the objects, and then join them together.

This is what I have so far:

```
getServicesAndStatuses(key: Key): Observable<Service[]> {
  return this.getServices(key)
    .flatMap((services: Service[]) => {
      if (services.length > 0) {
        return Observable.forkJoin(
          this.getEnvironmentStatus(key).map((statuses: ServiceStatus[]) => {
            services.forEach(service => {
              statuses.forEach(status => {
                if (status.virtualNetwork == key.virtualNetworkName && status.environment == key.environmentName && status.resource == service.resourceName && status.app == service.app.name) {
                  service.status = status;
                }
              });
              if (service.status == null) {
                service.status = new ServiceStatus();
              }
              console.log(service)
              return service;
            })
          })
        );
      }
      return Observable.of([]);
    });
}
```

I believe I'm missing a `return` because the console.log line correctly shows the service object with the status attached. But I can't figure out what I need.

Comment: why is this check `if (services.length > 0) {`?

Comment: I think that's leftover from a different approach I was working on

Comment: Actually, If I remove that check, I have a return type error Observable<Service[][]> is not assignable to type Observable<Service[]>

Comment: Is `this.getEnvironmentStatus(key)` an asynchronous call?

Comment: Yes, it does a `this.http.get('/status').map(mapHandler).catch(errorHandler)`

Comment: I'll tidy up the code

Comment: Actually, it might just be easier to say that the two other appService calls return mapped observables in the standard way (I just call the .subscribe() method in the component.) - I've used them in other components and they work fine - I'm building a bigger component which combines the two views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself with:

```
  getServicesAndStatuses(key: Key): Observable<Service[]> {
    return this.getEnvironmentServices(key)
      .flatMap((services: Service[]) => {
        return this.getEnvironmentStatus(key).map((statuses: ServiceStatus[]) => {
          services.forEach(service => {
            statuses.forEach(status => {
              if (status.virtualNetwork == key.virtualNetworkName && status.environment == key.environmentName && status.resource == service.resourceName && status.app == service.app.name) {
                service.status = status;
              }
            });
            if (service.status == null) {
              service.status = new ServiceStatus();
            }
            return service;
          });
          return services;
        })
      });
  }
```